# How to vectorize a torch function?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

When using `numpy` I can use `np.vectorize` to vectorize a function that contains `if` statements in order for the function to accept array arguments. How can I do the same with `torch` in order for a function to accept tensor arguments?

For example, the final print statement in the code below will fail. How can I make this work?

```
import numpy as np
import torch as tc

def numpy_func(x):
    return x if x > 0. else 0.
numpy_func = np.vectorize(numpy_func)

print('numpy function (scalar):', numpy_func(-1.))
print('numpy function (array):', numpy_func(np.array([-1., 0., 1.])))

def torch_func(x):
    return x if x > 0. else 0.

print('torch function (scalar):', torch_func(-1.))
print('torch function (tensor):', torch_func(tc.tensor([-1., 0., 1.])))
```

Comment: Can't you write it vectorized yourself?

Comment: Your vectorized example would be `return x.where(x > 0, 0)`

Comment: `pytorch` has [`functorch.vmap`](https://pytorch.org/functorch/stable/generated/functorch.vmap.html#functorch.vmap) but doesn't yet support `if` statements and would require `tensor` inputs.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Sorry, yes, I corrected the example code so that the torch function would take a tensor argument. This is what I meant to write initially. Too bad that `functorch.vmap` doesn't support `if` yet...

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: Your solution using `torch.where`, or `x.where` works for simple examples. But what if my function is more complicated?

Comment: @Mead if your function is complicated, then you won't get much of performance boost (especially if on GPU) compared to plain `for i in x.size: x[i] = f(x[i])`. You should be a mindful programmer and think about efficiency before you start implementing the `if` spaghetti for tensor manipulation

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: I'm not concerned with performance in this case. I want a simple way to get generic functions, which may contain `if` statements, to accept `tensor` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.apply_()` for CPU tensors. For CUDA ones, the task is problematic: `if` statements aren't easy to SIMDify.

You may apply the same workaround for `functorch.vmap` as video drivers used to do for shaders: evaluate both branches of the condition and stick to arithmetics.

Otherwise, just use a for loop: that's what `np.vectorize()` mostly [does anyway](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

```
def torch_vectorize(f, inplace=False):
    def wrapper(tensor):
        out = tensor if inplace else tensor.clone()
        view = out.flatten()
        for i, x in enumerate(view):
            view[i] = f(x)
        return out
    return wrapper
```